# Conditionally format crosstab cell based on aggregate values for row

Tags: aggregate, pivot-table, conditional-formatting, cognos, cognos-11

I have a cross tab report that has categories as the rows and the month/year. Additionally, I have the average and std dev for each row.

For instance:

|  | 2022-01 | 2022-02 | 2022-03 | Average(myData) | stdDev(myData) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| electrical | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| mechanical | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| admin | 1 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 3.46 |

Now, I am able to format the cells against a static value. For instance, I can set up a conditional format like this:

```
CellValue () > 2
```

This will allow me to highlight any crosstab intersection with a value greater than 2.

But I am at a loss on how to get this to work comparing it against the average and/or standard deviation

for instance, the following

```
CellValue ()>[myQuery].[Average(myData)]
```

highlights nothing, whereas I would have expected this to highlight any cell above average.

My end goal is to highlight any value that is above 1.645 * standard deviation + average, but I cannot even get a simpler rule to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something to work, but far from ideal.

I made queries to get the summary stats, then I joined those to the original data.

Then I put the categories and each of the summary stats on the left edge.

I could then reference them as expected in a conditional format. e.g. [mydata] > [myAve] + 1.645[myStdDev]

It isnt as straight forward as I would like, and it is a bit messy, but it works